# TCP sockets sr.readline prevents entering data on console?

Tags: .net, sockets, networking, tcplistener

Below you will find my code. THe thing is, this is supposed to be a "client chat" program so you would be able to send message constantly. However, somehow the app is blocked by console.readline() so the user is prompted to enter a message just once. Any workaround to this? May be using a predefined read buffer?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 7777);

            try
            {
                Stream s = client.GetStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                //Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Message: ");
                    string msg = Console.ReadLine();
                    sw.WriteLine(msg);
                    if (msg == "chao") break;
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }

                s.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, server code is here: http://pastebin.com/0Jgepy1Z

Comment: "the user is prompted to enter a message just once"  Probably because it gets stuck at `sr.ReadLine()`.  It's waiting for a response from the server, which never comes since the server never sends a message.  Try putting `sr.ReadLine()` into a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but if you have a read of Stephen Cleary's TCP/IP .Net Sockets FAQ you will get lots of information about using .NET sockets.

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

> sr.readline prevents entering data on console?

Correct. It blocks until a line has been received from the peer.